# static html files on azure blob storage as site architecture

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-blob-storage

Recently I've moved my website to Azure and learned of azure blob storage. My site contains a lot of static html files. Currently the files are generated by content admins and stored in specific folders, e.g. `/articles/some-article.html`. Is this a good idea, architecture and seo wise, to store those files as blobs and serve them to public users directly from the cdn? (change the links from `example.com/articles/some-article.html` to `cdn.example.com/articles/some-aritcle.html`).

### UPDATE

The html files will be directly consumed by public users. They will access them via links or direct url. Simply speaking, it's just about migrating static html articles/blog posts to azure blob storage instead of keeping them in a folder on the website server. They are standalone html files, that are rarely if at all rewritten. To further clarify, a user will browse a dynamic page, `example.com/articles` (mvc 5 website), and in that page there will be a list of links to the blobs:

```
<h1>This is an article about stuff</h1>
<p>description description description description description description description description description description description description </p>
<a href="http://cdn.example.com/articles/article-about-stuff.html">Read more</a>

<h1>This is another article about stuff</h1>
<p>description description description description description description description description description description description description </p>
<a href="http://cdn.example.com/articles/article-about-other-stuff.html">Read more</a>
```

Comment: Some questions: What purpose would these static HTML file serve? Will these be directly consumed by your users in the sense that they can access these files directly by typing the URL or clicking on a link in your application or will these files be consumed by your application (e.g. loading HTML files using AJAX)? Are you planning to host a static website using these files? Please update your question accordingly. Thx.

Comment: @GauravMantri updaed question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your use case, it makes complete sense to host these pages in blob storage. Moving them over to blob storage would free up some load on the web server (as now the static content will be served by blob storage). Also enabling CDN will improve overall user experience as the users will be served the content from the node closest to them.

However, please do keep in mind that you still can't host static websites using Azure Blob Storage and if the user types in some incorrect URL (or may be mess up with the links in your application [just for kicks :)], they will be shown standard blob storage error message. You don't get the ability to customize the error messages thrown by blob storage.

Comment: I did not consider error handling in case an article is removed. Maybe that is not a good idea after all.